# Launching a Bokeh server

Tags: python, bokeh

I am having trouble launching a Bokeh server on my PC. When executing:

```
bokeh serve --show sliders.py
```

Should this be entered in the command line of the files directory or should I be entering it in a python terminal?

**** EDIT ****

In the interests of sharing what I learned from this post, I have made my project open source on GutHub, please feel free to check it out below:

https://github.com/Ben-C-Harris/AutoTrader-Web-Scraping-Used-Car-Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the shell (command line). Go to the directory where you have your sliders.py file then execute this command.